# MySQL Multi-Source Replication errors via SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl

I have MySQL Multi-Source Replication (bare metal Ubuntu 22.04.2)with 140+ replication channels. Everything worked great until we switched replication to an [SSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-encrypted-connections.html) connection. After this, channels started giving an error:

```
Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'fdf2333a-f160-11ec-b70e-768162073097:27789449' at source log binlog.000563, end_log_pos 551. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
```

Then I found an error in the logs:

```
[ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Replica SQL for channel '####-###': Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'fdf2333a-f160-11ec-b70e-768162073097:27789449' at source log binlog.000563, end_log_pos 551; Could not execute Write_rows event on table ####-###.label_statistics; Duplicate entry '624304' for key 'label_statistics.PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's source log binlog.000563, end_log_pos 551, Error_code: MY-001062
```

It is interesting that not all channels produce an error, but only some of them (after about the 50th channel). That is, when restoring a new channel from a backup, it replicates without errors, but as soon as the next channel is restored, the previous one immediately produces a replication error.

Where to look for the source of the problem?

When SSL is disabled everything works fine again